# Objective c - DRDevice.h

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to check my "tray" to see if it open or not, but i can't get it to work, it says:

```
  "_DRDeviceIsTrayOpenKey", referenced from:

   ´ -[UntitledAppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] in UntitledAppDelegate.o

ld: symbol(s) not found
```

**the code is:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <DiscRecording/DRCoreDevice.h>
#import <DiscRecording/DRMSF.h>
#import <AvailabilityMacros.h>

extern NSString* const DRDeviceIsTrayOpenKey;

if (!DRDeviceIsTrayOpenKey == NO ) {
 [NSApp terminate:nil];
}
```

info:

**DRDeviceIsTrayOpenKey**

`extern NSString* const DRDeviceIsTrayOpenKey;`

**Discussion**
One of the keys in the dictionary returned by the status method. NSNumber containing a boolean value indicating whether the device's tray is open or not.

**Availability**
Introduced in Mac OS X v10.2

please help me fix that, i think my code is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your code is wrong.  That `DRDeviceIsTrayOpenKey` is a key used to retrieve a value from a `NSDictionary`.

So if you can get your Disk Recording status, you'd do something like this:

```
// this code would depend on you passing in a valid DRDevice object
// which I've named myDiscRecordingDevice. A computer can have multiple
// DVD / CD readers attached, so you need to specify which one you care about
NSDictionary * status = [myDiscRecordingDevice status];
NSString* state = [status objectForKey: DRDeviceMediaStateKey];

if ([state isEqualTo: DRDeviceMediaStateNone])
{
     if ([[status objectForKey: DRDeviceIsTrayOpenKey] boolValue])
         return trayOpen;

     return noDisc;
}
```

Comment: Good answer. Since the OP mentions an unresolved reference, you may want to remind him to include "DiscRecording.framework" to the project.

Comment: It says: /Users/me/Desktop/Untitled/UntitledAppDelegate.m:27:0 /Users/me/Desktop/Untitled/UntitledAppDelegate.m:27: error: 'myDiscRecordingDevice' undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: You need to modify my sample code up there to provide a `DRDevice` object (and there can be multiple ones, if you have multiple DVD / CD drives hooked to your computer). You also should modify my code to return YES or NO, depending on if the tray is open or closed.

Comment: I Have one  DVD / CD drive, let say it called " Mr_right " how can pass it as DRDevice object ? Like:  DRDevice * myDiscRecordingDevice = @["Mr_right"];

Comment: What you are trying to do is not trivial. You can *not* just create a `DRDevice` directly. The OS has to hand it to you (via the `DRNotificationCenter` or via IORegistry paths). Check out at the "Obtaining Device Instances" section at the top of Apple's [DRDevice documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/DiscRecordingFrameworkRef/DRDevice_h/Classes/DRDevice/index.html). And look for useful sample code ([like this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/DeviceListener/Listings/AppController_m.html). Good luck!